# How to style a WPF AutoCompleteBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

Probably a really simple mistake, I have downloaded the WPF toolkit and placed an AutoCompleteBox on my window. How can I create a style for this control? I have tried to follow msdn but no luck so far...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728668(v=vs.95).aspx

On my window I have:

```
<Controls:AutoCompleteBox style="{StaticResource acInput}"/>
```

In my styles I have the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:input="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Input"
                    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows">

    <Style x:Key="acInput" TargetType="input:AutoCompleteBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

But I have the error:
The name "AutoCompleteBox" does not exist in the namespace "clrnamespace:System.Windows.Controls.Input".

Comment: are you talking about Auto Select Text Box of wpf toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

Simply changed TargetType to "Controls:AutoCompleteBox"

```
<Style x:Key="acInput" TargetType="Controls:AutoCompleteBox">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following namespace reference:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
```